# Pytorch and Pytorch Lightning MultiGPU DDP slower than single GPU

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, multi-gpu

I have a basic pytorch with pytorch lightning code that I am trying to train on 2 RTX 2080Ti. Whenever I change the devices parameter of pytorch_lightning trainer from 1 to 2 the training speed goes down from ~45it/s to ~17it/s. I updated to the latest pytorch and pytorch_lightning. I added pin_memory=True to the dataloader.

```
lightning_module = ResNet50Model()

dataset = MNIST('./data', download=True, transform=transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor()
]))
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset,num_workers=0, pin_memory=True)

trainer = pl.Trainer(
    # strategy=DDPStrategy(find_unused_parameters=False),
    limit_train_batches=100,
    max_epochs=20,
    devices=1,
    accelerator="gpu",
    # profiler="simple"
)

trainer.fit(model=lightning_module, train_dataloaders=train_loader)
```

I am using python 3.8 on ubuntu 18.04
I tried pytorch 1.12.1, 1.13.1 and 2.0
I tried pytorch_lightning 1.9.4, 1.9.5 and 2.0.4

The profiler does not really show useful information. It is just that training epochs are taking more time.

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: I notice you have `num_workers=0`. This could be the bottleneck. Try to increase num_workers to your number of CPU cores.